# DLL function call is not working

Tags: c#, dll

I have created a DLL named ClassLibrary1.dll.
It contains just one function **iscalled()** inside class **Class1**.

```
//Function of DLL
public bool iscalled()
  {
     return true;
  }
```

Now I have created a new project of WINFORM and added a reference there of my own dll **ClassLibrary1**.

Below is the code snippet of winForm Code

```
[DllImport("ClassLibrary1.dll")]
public static extern bool iscalled();


public void mydllcall1()
 {          
     bool ud = iscalled();
     MessageBox.Show(ud.ToString());
 }
```

When I am running the application, an error is encountered stating

> Unable to find an entry point named 'iscalled' in DLL 'ClassLibrary1.dll

I am looking for some solution.

Thanks and Regards

Subham Kumar, 
Nathcorp

Comment: Have you tried to make „iscalled“ static?

Comment: Which language did you use to write your dll, C# or C++?

Comment: @GrantHoward C#

Comment: @Oswald Not yet.. I have tried using static to iscalled, but don't worked as well.

Comment: C# dll doesn't need to use DllImport, just add the reference, import namespace (using ClassLibrary1) and call your method. DllImport is for native dlls (usually written in C/C++).

Comment: OK @GrantHoward .But what if I don't know language in which dll is written.
I am trying to use NI4882.dll, and I have used .net reflector to break the dll, and I found that class is marked as internal and sealed , then how can I call those class's function as I can't inherit class as well as can't create object of that class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cant call `DLLImport` on a .net assembly. (The DLLImport attribute is for standard [Dynamic-Link Libraries](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682589(v=vs.85).aspx)). You need to instead use `Assembly.Load` or similar

[How to: Load Assemblies into an Application Domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/app-domains/how-to-load-assemblies-into-an-application-domain)

> There are several ways to load an assembly into an application domain.
>   The recommended way is to use the static (Shared in Visual Basic) `Load`
>   method of the `System.Reflection.Assembly` class. Other ways assemblies
>   can be loaded include:
>
> - The LoadFrom method of the Assembly class loads an assembly given its
>     file location. Loading assemblies with this method uses a different
>     load context.
> - The `ReflectionOnlyLoad` and `ReflectionOnlyLoadFrom` methods load an
>     assembly into the reflection-only context. Assemblies loaded into this
>     context can be examined but not executed, allowing the examination of
>     assemblies that target other platforms.

**Example**

```
public static void Main()
{
    // Use the file name to load the assembly into the current
    // application domain.
    Assembly a = Assembly.Load("example");
    // Get the type to use.
    Type myType = a.GetType("Example");
    // Get the method to call.
    MethodInfo myMethod = myType.GetMethod("MethodA");
    // Create an instance.
    object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(myType);
    // Execute the method.
    myMethod.Invoke(obj, null);
}
```

**Further reading**

[Assembly.Load Method (AssemblyName)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x4cw969y(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the entry point

```
[DllImport("ClassLibrary1.dll", EntryPoint = "iscalled", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool iscalled();
```

Comment: I have used what you proposed but getting Same error.

Comment: your dll is written in which language ?

Comment: It is written in c#.

Comment: then you can add refrence to you dll simply and then create object of class as Class1 obj=new Class1(); and access method as obj.isCalled()

Comment: Yeah, I have used that, but I want to access dll's function using DLLImport().

Comment: You cannot use DllImport for managed DLLs, so this is certainly not the method to achieve your requirement

Comment: I have one more question. How can I call dll's function whose class is internal and sealed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168892/discussion-between-kritikatalwar-and-subham).